# Red-eyed anarchy

Tags: idiom-meaning

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22red-eyed+anarchy%22

"the world still went wondering why red-eyed anarchy...", and "listening to the exposition of red-eyed anarchy", and "more than ever ready for red-eyed anarchy of any sort"

What "red-eyed anarchy" mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd offer **see red**, **seeing red**, **blood-eyed**, or even **blood in his eyes** as a synonym for "red-eyed."

"Red-eyed anarchy" is a raw, angry, emotional, and violent form of anarchy where people will really hurt and kill others.

This is not Sex Pistol *Anarchy in the UK* concert [2] anarchy where everyone goes home after the show with a couple bruises, or firing off an angry email. Red-eyed anarchy is French-revolution anarchy [3], where there are violent insurrections, a lot of injuries and deaths, and people get beheaded.

Cambridge dictionary defines "see red" as:

> to become very angry [1]

I don't know if you've ever been that angry, but I had a case of road rage once where I was absolutely furious at some idiotic driver. I actually *saw red*; my vision had a reddish hue. I'm not certain why (perhaps blood vessels in the eyes getting swollen out of anger), but anyway, it can happen.

Some also say that the saying comes from the Spanish bullfighting, where angry *el toros* see the red cape and charge, attempting to gore/kill the matador. Bulls have a legendary fury like no other animal; like the bronze bull on Wall Street--which was actually tagged with the circle-A anarchy symbol in 2012. [5]

Look at the furious attacks of the bulls in the vid linked at refererence [4], and imagine this anger in people: *that* is red-eyed anarchy.

1. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/see-red
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBojbjoMttI
3. https://medium.com/@The_Historian/french-revolution-a-bloody-event-that-changed-the-
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8WjM-b3-uI&bpctr=1612675757
5. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charging_Bull#Vandalism

Comment: Thank you, very interesting